# Show that $\left\|\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx\right\|\leq\int\limits_a^b\|f(x)\|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a map, $f=(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ and let

$$\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx= \left(\int\limits_a^b f_1(x)\,dx, \cdots, \int\limits_a^b f_n(x)\,dx\right)$$

Show that

$$\left\|\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx\right\|\leq\int\limits_a^b\|f(x)\|dx$$

I want to know if this property still true for map. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming the norm is the euclidean norm:

Let $I=\int f$. Note that $||\int f||^2=||I||^2=I\cdot I=I\cdot\int f$. Let $g(x)=I\cdot f(x)$ and note that $g(x)\le||I||\,||f(x)||$. So
$$||I||\left|\left|\int f\right|\right|=\left|\left|\int f\right|\right|^2=I\cdot\int f=\int I\cdot f=\int g\le\int||I||\,||f||=||I||\int||f||.$$

Comment: ??? First, $I\int f$ is not a vector, it's the product of two vectors, which is undefined. Second, I don't see any $I\int f$ in my post! I see $I\cdot \int f$ in a few places...

Comment: I see now you mean inner product, never mind

Comment: One might say I should have specified that \cdot meant the inner product. One might then reply that it's hard to see what else it could mean, when I write $v\cdot w$ all over the place, where $v$ and $w$ are vectors...

Comment: I went from the definition $I = \int f$ to the displayed line. Because the answer was short I thought that would be enough. This is not worth discussing.