# $|\int f |≤\int|f|$ in complex

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I could find several answers that $|\int fd\mu| \leqq \int |f| d\mu$ when $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable function.
But, how I can explain when $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb C$?

When does the equality holds?

Comment: Many different proofs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538166/how-can-i-prove-the-inequality-about-integration-of-complex-valued-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: HINT: use the definition of $\int f\,d \mu $